# Blockchain (Avalanche) faucet implementation in the local test network

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, blockchain, ethereum, yarnpkg

I am trying to implement a faucet for my local testnet which consists of 5 node. To do that I followed the avalances github documentation as in the link,

[https://github.com/ava-labs/avalanche-faucet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJyP3.jpg)

In short, basically, I run my 5 nodes and all nodes runs successfully using an Ubuntu Sandbox. Also, the bootstrap is finished. Then tried to run the below command in the Ubuntu,

**Platform Versions:** Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
**node-js** v16.2.0
**npm** 7.15.0
**Yarn** 1.22.5

**Creating Faucet:**

1. Clone the repository `git clone https://github.com/ava-labs/avalanche-faucet.git`
2. Go to the root directory cd avalanche-faucet
3. Install javascript dependencies with `yarn install`.
4. Create a .env file by copying .env.example
5. Install AvalancheGo, our Avalanche node client written in Golang to spin up a network (https://github.com/ava-labs/avalanchego).

**Running Project:**

1. Make sure you have installed and able to run an Avalanche node properly.
2. All environment variables are correct and your private key has funds in it.
3. Run the project with hot reloading `yarn serve`

Everything is goes ok but when I run `yarn serve` then the below Error pop up. **"Assertion `thread_id_key != 0x7777' failed."**

```
43% building 275/282 modules 7 active ...cet/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/home/avalanchelocal1/Downloads/avalanche-faucet/node_modules/vuetify/lib/services/index.jsnode: ../src/coroutine.cc:134: void* find_thread_id_key(void*): Assertion `thread_id_key != 0x7777' failed.
```

Aborted (core dumped)
error Command failed with exit code 134.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

[image]

Comment: We tried the steps from [the AVA faucet](https://medium.com/avalancheavax/the-ava-platform-tools-pt-2-the-ava-faucet-48f28da57146). Tried it on Ubuntu server and it is working fine. Though it needs `node` and `npm` to be installed instead of `yarn`. Hope it works for you too :-)